# Azure Web Site EF Code First Migration

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, entity-framework, azure

I have a small website that I had published to Azure with it's SQL database. I then did some changes and published again.  The Publish works fine but when I try to run it I get a problem due to the EF Code First Migration.

The relevant code in the migration file is this

```
 CreateTable(
                "dbo.CallQuestions",
                Function(c) New With
                    {
                        .Call_ID = c.Int(nullable := False),
                        .Q_ID = c.Int(nullable := False),
                        .Q_Resp = c.Int(nullable := False)
                    }) _
                .PrimaryKey(Function(t) New With { t.Call_ID, t.Q_ID })
```

The error is this :

> The properties expression 't => Convert(new
>   VB$AnonymousType_23`2(Call_ID = t.call_id, Q_ID = t.q_id))' is not
>   valid. The expression should represent a property: C#: 't =>
>   t.MyProperty'  VB.Net: 'Function(t) t.MyProperty'. When specifying
>   multiple properties use an anonymous type: C#: 't => new {
>   t.MyProperty1, t.MyProperty2 }'  VB.Net: 'Function(t) New With {
>   t.MyProperty1, t.MyProperty2 }'.

Since it all runs fine on my local machine, and the migration file code looks right, what am I missing ?